# Cake php 2.1 form error

Tags: cakephp, view

I am using cakephp 2.1 when i am creating add function in controller and view add.ctp

i am getting this error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\rohitchoudhary\caketoodoo\app\View\tasks\add.ctp on line 5**

Please help me

Comment: My crystal ball is at the cleaner right now. Could you please show the code in add.ctp, at the very least line 5?

Comment: <?php echo $this->Form->create('Task');?>
<fieldset>
<legend>Add New Task</legend>
<?php
 echo $this>Form->input('title');
 echo $this->Form->input('done');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Add Task');?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not a cake but a php question.
and not even that.

just make sure you use a decent PHP IDE which would give parsing errors.
then you would find out that you probably placed an invalid char somewhere.
either way you should be able to debug such a parse error yourself.

such error messages are always descriptive enough to get it done on your own.